# Is it possible to set a DHCP server on WSL/Linux?

Tags: server, windows-subsystem-for-linux, dhcp

I'm trying to set a DHCP server on WSL/Linux. But, when I try to start the service I receive the following message:

Launching IPv4 server only.
[FAIL] Starting ISC DHCPv4 server: dhcpd[....] check syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
 failed!

Anyone could help?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.  Also, if I said "yes", then what?